# Making an object dynamically

Tags: javascript

How can I make an object dynamically in Javascript ?

**What I Expect**

```
var tree_data = {
    'for-sale' : {name: 'For Sale', type: 'folder'} ,
    'vehicles' : {name: 'Vehicles', type: 'folder'} ,
    'rentals' : {name: 'Rentals', type: 'folder'}   ,
    'real-estate' : {name: 'Real Estate', type: 'folder'}   ,
    'pets' : {name: 'Pets', type: 'folder'} ,
    'tickets' : {name: 'Tickets', type: 'item'} ,
    'services' : {name: 'Services', type: 'item'}   ,
    'personals' : {name: 'Personals', type: 'item'}
}
```

**My Try**

```
// Here I remove all white space from my string 
var nome = result[indice].Texto.replace(/ /g, '');

// Here I create the item
var novoMenu = {
      pasta: {
           name: result[indice].Texto,
           type: "folder"
      }
}

// and then fill my object
self.tree_data.push(novoMenu);
```

But this way my tree_data object becomes like

```
{ 
   pasta: {
         name: "For Sale',
         type: 'Folder'
   }
}
```

`pasta` should be the `name` without whitespace. How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `push()` call in a loop?

Comment: @Barmar is a Ajax return. In Texto we have 'For Sale' for example.

Comment: what do you mean "pasta should be the name without whitespaces"? This JavaScript object you created has exactly the same structure as the tree_data you expect.

Comment: @DonRhummy The structure is the same but all my data will be { pasta: { name: 'For Sale', type: 'Folder' }, pasta: { name: 'For Rental', type: 'Folder' }. I.E. the name 'Pasta' will repeat

Comment: @Lucas_Santos of course, because you HARD CODED it in there.

Comment: @DonRhummy But how can I do this more flexible ? like in the sample

Comment: Where does `pasta` magically come from? Also, this has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the name as the index into the object:

```
// Here I remove all white space from my string 
var theName = result[indice].Texto.replace(/ /g, ''); //Shouldn't this be .replace(/ /g, '-') ?

// Here I create the item
var novoMenu = {};
novoMenu[ theName ] = {
           name: result[indice].Texto,
           type: "folder"
      }
};

// and then fill my json array
self.tree_data.push(novoMenu);
```

Answer (score 1):

`tree_data` is an object, not an array. It should be initialized as:

```
self.tree_data = {};
```

Then your loop should add to it with:

```
self.tree_data[nome] = novoMenu;
```